# in a spring mvc controller access arraylist element where the contains of the arraylist is class objects

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, arraylist

Doing this Project in Spring MVC
My MVC controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/cars", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ArrayList<Car> update(@RequestBody ArrayList<Car> cars) {
System.out.println(cars.get(0)); 

/* How can I get the color separately for the cars.get(0) and cars.get(0) */    


    return (cars);
}

}
```

My car.java POJO

```
package com.rev.retpostjson;

public class Car {

private String VIN;
private String color;
private Integer miles;

public String getVIN() {
    return VIN;
}
public void setVIN(String vIN) {
    VIN = vIN;
}
public String getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}
public Integer getMiles() {
    return miles;
}
public void setMiles(Integer miles) {
    this.miles = miles;
}

}
```

My input JSON

```
[


 {
"color":"Blue",
"miles":200,
"vin":"1234"


 },


 {
"color":"Red",
"miles":500,
"vin":"1235"


 }
]
```

My output JSON

```
[


{
"color": "Blue",
"miles": 200,
"vin": "1234"


 },


 {
"color": "Red",
"miles": 500,
"vin": "1235"



}
]
```

The `System.out.println(cars.get(0));` inside the controller displays `{color=Blue, miles=200, vin=1234}` in the console.  I want to use the value of the color separately i.e. the color of the `cars.get(0)` and `cars.get(1)` so that I can write some logic depending on that color. I tried those things `String f=cars.get(0).toString();` `String f=cars.get(0);`   `Car f=cars.get(0);System.out.println(f.getColor());` and `cars.get(0).getColor()`
But every time I found error like following

```
[Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.rev.retpostjson.Car] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.rev.retpostjson.Car
```

I have not been able to understand where I am wrong.How to achieve the desired goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `getColor()` method ,

```
Car objCar1 = cars.get(0);
System.out.println("color is "+objCar.getColor());
```

will give you the color of the car

Comment: I tried it and also mentioned it in the question that it not working...The error which I get after trying this has also been mentioned above.

Comment: Seems you tried it with the `String` , can you please try the above one

Comment: No Sir I tried like this `Car f=cars.get(0);System.out.println(f.getColor());`

Comment: what does that print ?

Comment: Does not print anything.I get the below error in the console `SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/retpostjson] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.rev.retpostjson.Car] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.rev.retpostjson.Car


`

Comment: The error is thrown elsewhere , the url pattern `/retpostjson`  doesnt match here . Check for other methods or the subsequent actions.

Comment: how did you send the POST request?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting JSON object, which you need to parse and make an object of POJO.

You can have one more VO class like car, let say CarListVO where you can have list of car as instance variable then you need to modify your code little bit.

```
declare view in your controller or BaseController 
@Resource(name = "jacksonJsonView")
protected View jsonView;

public ModelAndView update(@RequestBody CarListVO carVOs) {
            List<Car> cars = carVOs.getCarList();
            cars.get(0).getColor();

     return new ModelAndView(jsonView, "data", cars);
    }

class CarListVO {
    public List<Car> carList;

    public List<Car> getCarList() {
        return carList;
    }
    public void setCarList(List<Car> carList) {
        this.carList = carList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir Can you please give the structure of this VO class.

Comment: Sir what does this getCarList() method will look like? `public ArrayList<Car> getCarList() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 }`

Comment: Sir The console does not give any error list but I am getting a 400 Bad Request response instead of the json

Comment: you can use ModelAndView  for returning Json data

Answer (score 0):

`cars.get(0).getColor()` this is working. I tested it.